# MVC 3 Chart Helper with more than 9 xValues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to use the MVC 3 Chart helper to create a bar chart that might have more than 9 xValues.  The following code will produce a chart that only has labels for "two, four, six, eight and ten".  I'd like the chart to diplay all labels, one through ten.

```
var companies = new[] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten" };
var quantities = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

Chart chart = new Chart(960, 600, theme: ChartTheme.Blue)
    .AddTitle("Quantity Shipped by Company")
    .AddSeries(chartType: "bar", xValue: companies, yValues: quantities);
```

I've seen a few references to setting the interval, but I don't think they pertain to the MVC 3 Chart helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the chart helper lacking in a few areas and a little buggy.  When I encountered problems, I created the chart manually.  Take a look at the code I posted here:

[ASP.NET MVC 3 MSChart Error: Only 1 Y values can be set for this data series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887292/asp-net-mvc-3-mschart-error-only-1-y-values-can-be-set-for-this-data-series/5893935#5893935)

Comment: Thanks Kyle. I did find a fix for this. (I must wait to answer per the SO rules for noobs). Your example did lead me to finally abandon the chart helper for a similar solution.

Comment: Turns out my fix didn't work.  Will recommend to anyone else to just create the chart yourself as Kyle suggested.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be an easy fix.  I used the Chart.SetXAxis(max: 10).  The trick is that you must use the exact length of your xValues.  Any more and .SetXAxis() seems to just ignore the value.  I've changed my example code to:

```
var companies = new[] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten" };
var quantities = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

Chart chart = new Chart(960, 600, theme: ChartTheme.Blue)
    .SetXAxis(max: companies.Length)
    .AddTitle("Quantity Shipped by Company")
    .AddSeries(chartType: "bar", xValue: companies, yValues: quantities);
```

I do agree with Kyle though in that the Chart helper is lacking in many areas.  I've since abandoned it for "system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting" which provides more options and better documentation.

**Edit:**

This came up again for a friend of mine who had 12 records.  This solution did NOT work.  I'm going with Kyle's answer and abandoning the chart helper all together.