# Data points insertion error. Only 1 Y values can be set for this data series

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, charts

I am trying to display a chart that is connected with my db. But it will generate an error. The error is "Data points insertion error. Only 1 Y values can be set for this data series." Please help me.
The code is given below:

```
public partial class chart3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataTable dt;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(@"connectionString");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from GraphChart",con);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        Chart1.DataSource = dt;
        Chart1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Source:

```
<div>
 <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server"  CssClass="auto-style1" Width="423px">
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Series1" XValueMember="Name"></asp:Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Series2" YValueMembers="Age"></asp:Series>

            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
            <Legends>
                <asp:Legend Title="Employee Data"></asp:Legend>
            </Legends> 
        </asp:Chart>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have sample data and the SQL/Data Table definition? Maybe you have duplicate names, or are values stored in the wrong columns

Comment: @Pieter21 : I have a table named as "GraphChart" and it contains 3 columns. They are, 1. NameId, 2. Name, 3. Age and it contains some sample values. eg: 1, abc, 10

Comment: @Pieter21 : Do you have any idea why this error happens. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given below code is working. Thank you all.

```
public partial class chart3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(@"connectionString");
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from GraphChart",con);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataView source = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
        Chart1.DataSource = source; 
        Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Name";
        Chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Age";
        Chart1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably setting the label instead of real data.

Maybe this link can help: [ASP.NET MVC 3 MSChart Error: Only 1 Y values can be set for this data series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887292/asp-net-mvc-3-mschart-error-only-1-y-values-can-be-set-for-this-data-series)